# Plug & Play WSS servers

Tags: javascript, browser, https, ca, ws

My plan is to build a small file sharing P2P network on WSS, because in this way browsers have the possibility to connect directly to peers and they can leech. But I encountered a problem, as a normal P2P network, peers are "plug and play" you just download the client and with double click you open it and maybe the next day you uninstall it, but Web Secure Sockets require a CA-signed certificate and this will cause lots of problems in all fronts.

There are some solutions that I thought:

Use letsencrypt and at installation automatically sign a certificate. But letsencrypt doesn't support signing for IPs, so an user needs a domain and this is a worse problem than a signed certificate.

Use a self-signed certificate generated at installation time. The major part of browsers will create very intimidating warnings and some browsers doesn't even permit it.

Use WS without encryption. In theory this is good for security, this P2P protocol has its own encryption, but browsers will make some warnings as "mixed content" and probably in the future plain HTTP and WS will be treated like a self signed certificate.

Any recommendation? Is very strange that doesn't exist a public accepted solution for a simple pseudo-tcp connection. I say public accepted because plain WS can do the trick as plain TCP does, but now it is seen in a very bad way by browsers.